# Genrate 32-bit exe's on 64-bit machine using python pyinstaller

Tags: python, pyinstaller, exe, 32bit-64bit

I am creating desktop application using python i have 64 bit windows system i want to generate 32 bit exe using pyinstaller. i have already installed 32 bit and 64 bit both python in my system and i am creating virtual environment also for generating both exe, but it display error as below when i am checking 32 bit exe.

```
**This version of exe is not compatible with version of windows you're running.check your computer's system information and then contact the software publisher.**
```

Comment: Check the first note on https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/stable/operating-mode.html. ''The output of PyInstaller is specific to the active operating system and the active version of Python''

Answer (score 1):

You'd need to:

- install 32-bit version of Python
- use that Python to create your virtual environment
- use that virtual environment to bundle your program